# Implementation of Style in Edit Text

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any java code to implement the style(ie,bold italics etc) in the edit text and not the text view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditText inherits from TextView

```
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Use what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I wan't aware that it inherits from Textview.